# Let $A,B \subseteq X$. If $A\cap B= X$, then can we say $A^c\subseteq B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A,B\subseteq X$. If $A\cap B= X$, then can we say $A^c\subseteq B$?

The quesion is short, thanks for answers and comments.

Comment: I suspect you rather want *union* in the hypothesis: $A\cup B=X$.

Comment: How can you say $A,B \in X$ as if they are elements, yet define their intersection to be that set? This doesn't make sense...

Comment: As written: if you mean $A, B \subseteq X$, then $A \cap B = X$ implies $A = B = X$, so...

Comment: Edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you mean $A,B \subseteq X$ and are assuming $A \cup B = X$. Then we do indeed get the result you stated.

Let $x \in A^c$. Then $x \in X$, but $x \notin A$. But since $X = A \cup B$, we must have $x \in A$ or $x \in B$ (or both). Since $x \in A$ is ruled out, we must have $x \in B$.

This shows that for every $x$, $x \in A^c$ implies $x \in B$. We conclude that $A^c \subseteq B$.

If you instead assume that $A \cap B = X$, then we still get the result, albeit a bit more trivially. Since $A \subseteq X$ and $X = A \cap B \subseteq A$, we must have $A=X$. In the same way, $B = X$. Thus $A^c = \varnothing$, and so trivially $A^c \subseteq B$.

Comment: Thanks for answer.

Comment: @Sambo. At the beginning, Why do you say that " x belongs to X", just after having said that " x belongs to the complement of A". ( Is X supposed to be the universal set here?). What did I miss?

Comment: @EleonoreSaintJames My implicit assumption was that $A^c$ meant $X \backslash A$, since the sets we're concerned with ($A$ and $B$) are subsets of $X$. While it is true that "$x \in A^c$" could just be shorthand for "$x \notin A$", usually the use of the complement notation means the complement within a larger set, since otherwise "$A^c$" is not a set.